# INSERT MULTIPLE HTML pages into specified DIV using a list of links

Tags: html, hyperlink, insert

I'm having an issue here and can't seem to think of what the solution is. I need to avoid PHP and JAVA if possible since I dont write in that code yet.

Basically I have 18 products/links and one div to display one page at a time inside the Div. Each link should call on the HTML page that is in the sites folder but only show when link is selected.

Help on this subject would be greatly appreciated. Someone helped me using js but for some odd reason its not working for me: See Code:

---

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabcontent.js"></script>
________________________________________________________________


<div id="textBox_prodLine">
        <p style="line-height: 26px;">
        <b>
        <a class="prodList" href="#" rel="tcontent1">+ Soft Touch | Lotionized Hand Soap</a><br>
        <a class="prodList" href="#" rel="tcontent2">+ Pure Touch | Anti-Bacterial Hand Soap</a><br>
        <a class="prodList" href="#" rel="tcontent3">+ Soft Foam | Foaming Hand Soap</a><br>
        <a class="prodList" href="#" rel="tcontent4">+ Sanatouch | Hand Sanitizer</a><br>
        <a class="prodList" href="#" rel="tcontent5">+ Suds Up | Pot & Pan Dish Soap</a><br>
        <a class="prodList" href="#" rel="tcontent6">+ Neutra | Neutral Cleaner</a><br>
        <a class="prodList" href="#" rel="tcontent7">+ Neutra | Lemon Scented Neutral Cleaner</a><br>
        <a class="prodList" href="#" rel="tcontent8">+ Windshine | Glass Cleaner</a><br>
        <a class="prodList" href="#" rel="tcontent9">+ HDX-99 | Heavy Duty Degreaser</a><br>
        <a class="prodList" href="#" rel="tcontent10">+ Rug Rescue | Carpet Spot Remover</a><br>
        <a class="prodList" href="#" rel="tcontent11">+ Biospray | RTU Cleaner/Disinfectant</a><br>
        <a class="prodList" href="#" rel="tcontent12">+ Big Blue | Low Temp Rinse Aid</a><br>
        <a class="prodList" href="#" rel="tcontent13">+ Big Blue | High Temp Rinse Aid</a><br>
        <a class="prodList" href="#" rel="tcontent14">+ Big Red | Heavy Duty Dish Detergent</a><br>
        <a class="prodList" href="#" rel="tcontent15">+ Big Yellow | Chlorine & Destainer</a><br>
        <a class="prodList" href="#" rel="tcontent16">+ Sparkle | Toilet Bowl Cleaner</a><br>
        <a class="prodList" href="#" rel="tcontent17">+ Sunbryte | Cream Cleanser</a><br>
        <a class="prodList" href="#" rel="tcontent18">+ Lemonshine | High Foaming Pot & Pan Detergent</a><br>
       </b>
    <br>
    </p>
    </div>

    <div id="prodWrapper">
    <div id="tcontent1" class="tabcontent">
    <object data="softtouch.htm"></object>
    THIS SHOULD BE AN HTM FILE FROM INSIDE THE SITE WHEN LINK SELECTED ABOVE<br />
    </div>

    <div id="tcontent2" class="tabcontent">
    THIS SHOULD BE THE SECOND HTM FILE FROM INSIDE THE SITE WHEN LINK SELECTED ABOVE<br />
    </div>

    <div id="tcontent3" class="tabcontent">
    THIS SHOULD BE THE THIRD HTM FILE FROM INSIDE THE SITE WHEN LINK SELECTED ABOVE<br />
    </div>

    <div id="tcontent4" class="tabcontent">
    THIS SHOULD BE THE FOURTH HTM FILE FROM INSIDE THE SITE WHEN LINK SELECTED ABOVE<br />
    </div>
    </div>

________________________________________________________________

<script type="text/javascript">

var myflowers=new ddtabcontent("prodWrapper")
myflowers.setpersist(true)
myflowers.setselectedClassTarget("link") //"link" or "linkparent"
myflowers.init()

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var mypets=new ddtabcontent("pettabs")
mypets.setpersist(true)
mypets.setselectedClassTarget("link")
mypets.init(2000)

</script>

________________________________________________________________

CSS:

.tabcontent{
display:none;
}

@media print {
.tabcontent {
display:block !important;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to put an iframe in the div using HTML (`<div><iframe id="frame1" height="100%" width="100%" src="page-one.html"></iframe></div>`).

Then you can make a JavaScript function to change the content:

```
function changeContent(url) {
    document.getElementById("frame1").src = url;
}
```

And then you could change it using the HTML: `<button onClick="changeContent('page-two.html')">Page 2</button>`.

Just seen your code, using `<a>` tags, you can still achieve this by using the onClick attribute and set the href attribute to # (`<a href="#" onClick="changeContent('page-two.html')">Page 2</a>`).

Comment: I used the iframe in one instance but the slide bar keept on appearing. So I dropped it. I guess I could probably get rid of the scroll bar though?

Comment: Yep, this is easy to do in your css. Just set `iframe {overflow: hidden;}`, or you could even do this in the iframe style attribute. If you liked my answer, could you please +1 it.

Comment: I see, I will revert to the iframe and try the java. If I have an issue I'll get in touch again! Thanks Zak!

Comment: I think you mean JavaScript, the two are often confused. Java runs on a virtual machine and JavaScript runs on a webpage!